# How to create a loop that will find files with a specific name, and give folders lacking that file?

Tags: bash, shell

New to bash, trying to make the following loop to see which of my folders are missing my notes.

I have several folders named after my courses under a larger "data" folder, for simplicity sake we will call them folder1, folder2, etc. Some folders have files titled some iteration of course, course notes, etc, others do not. I have a large number of folders, so I am trying to create a loop that will tell me which ones lack my notes.

Example:

```
mainfolder
 -folder1
 -folder2
  -notesfile
 -folder3
  -coursenote
 -folder4
etc.
```

So far I have:

```
for file in mainfolder/* /*; do
find "course" $file
```

I'm not getting a proper output of files with notes yet. How do I fix this, and make it so I get an output of **which *folder* doesn't have** "notes"?

Comment: Please elaborate how we can identify the `note` files.
Do they contain some specific substring in the filename,
or include some word in the lines of the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
for folder in data/*; do
        HASFILE=false
        for file in  "$folder"/*; do
                #[ -f "find $file -name "*notes*"" ]
                if find $file -name "*notes*" | grep -q .; then
                        HASFILE=true
                fi
        done
        if [ "$HASFILE" != true ]; then
                echo "$folder has NO notes!"
        fi
done
```